# Getting info from nodes in CDATA with Xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath, rss, nodes, cdata

I have a little problem with getting the correct info from my RSS-feed.

This is how the feed looks like.

```
<description>
<![CDATA[<img height="64" width="64" align="top" src="http://www.festivalfoton.nu/images/festivaler/skogsrojet.jpg" alt="" title="" width="222" height="222" />
<datum>1 - 2 augusti</datum>
<stad>Rejmyre</stad>
<pris>690 kronor</pris>]]>
</description>
```

I've tried to fetch the info inside the different nodes ,  and  with this command:

```
[data:row("description/stad")]
```

But nothing happens and I've learned that it has to do with CDATA.

What can I do? Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

CDATA encodes text nodes which you can query using `description/text()`. You cannot query the "nodes" inside, as they are none (but only large plain text node).

Possible solutions:

- Fix the input to actually hand over XML data instead of text nodes
- Parse the text node as XML again (but watch out, it's no valid XML as it lacks a common root node)
- Use some proprietary extensions that *might* be available to parse the text nodes again, but most probably these will only be available in fully-fledged and more recent XQuery/XSLT engines (which include XPath as embedded language).
- "Fix" the XML before parsing and remove the CDATA tag using regular expressions/string search. Really ugly solution and much more likely to break, but depends on what you need to do and how often (single time analysis or long-running server software?).